# Как присвоить select для form.CharFiled без виджета Select

Tags: django

Нужно в html форму добавить, чтобы из тега  `SELECT` или `OPTION` инфа передалась на конкретное поле `form.CharFiled`. Нужно это для того, чтобы сделать логику в `SELECT`. Так как некоторые  `OPTION` могут быть недоступны в зависимости от значения в `Product(models.Model)`

Так если `item_1 = False, item_2 = True`, то в html бует следующее:

```
 <select>
    {% if item_1 %}
       <option>Item1</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% if item_2 %}
       <option>Item2</option>
    {% endif %}
 </select>
```

Пользователь выберет только `item_2` и нужно это значение были записано в обычное поле `form.CharField`. То есть присвоить или  `SELECT` или `OPTION` значение `{{ form.items_example }}`

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к тегу  атрибут name, значение которого будет равно названию поля CharField в вашей модели. Тогда при отправке формы, джанга сможет правильно распарсить POST запрос и сделает всё так, как вы хотите:

`<select name="kefal">
    {% if item_1 %}
       <option>Item1</option>
    {% endif %}
    {% if item_2 %}
       <option>Item2</option>
    {% endif %}
 </select>`

Где поле выглядит так:

`kefal = forms.CharField()`